# Facebook Ads not showing android

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing and android application that needs to show Facebook Banner Ads, for that i have successfully generated Placement id and implemented the code suggested by Facebook developers website. But the problem is that ads are not showing. On debugging i find out this No Fill Error. I have searched this error on google but could not able to solve it. Any help will be appreciated. Here is my code :

```
AdView adView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Instantiate an AdView view
    adView = new AdView(this, PLACEMENT_ID, AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);

    // Find the main layout of your activity
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.activityLayout);

    // Add the ad view to your activity layout
    layout.addView(adView);

    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

        @Override
        public void onError(Ad ad, AdError error) {
            // Ad failed to load. 
            // Add code to hide the ad's view
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
            // Ad was loaded
            // Add code to show the ad's view
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {
            // Use this function to detect when an ad was clicked.
        }

    });


    // Request to load an ad    
    adView.loadAd();
}
```

Comment: Possible paste your error/stacktrace debug details here which can solve your problem.

Comment: @Madhukar Hebbar in my few android devices showing ads from facebook and facebook console it showing like app in review and they are telling like we will show you ads once we get good traffic

Answer (score 2):

After lots of searching i find out the solution why ads are not showing, actually my application is not live(in google play store) so try to login on your application with that Facebook account through which Placement id is generated. It will work.